# While loop for loading files not working

Tags: c++, file-io, while-loop, ifstream

I'm trying to make a linked list that adds emails from a text file in the order they were received. The while loop, that I'm using to retrieve email info and make new nodes, is not even completing a single iteration (I tested it with an integer and another condition for stopping). My .txt file worked when loading it with someone else's program, so I believe my source_file.get aren't working?

```
int Classify::Load_email(char filename[]) {
    ifstream source_file(filename);
    char eof_prime;
    if(!source_file) // Checks whether there is anything in the file
        return 0;
    if(!email_head) { // If there is no head, creates a new node for it to point to, and have tail point to it as well
        email_head = new email_node;
        email_tail = email_head;
        email_tail->next = NULL;
    }
    source_file >> eof_prime; // Primes the eof function.

     while(!(source_file.eof())); {
        source_file.get(email_tail->email_data.sent, 50, '|');
        source_file.get(email_tail->email_data.from, 50, '|');
        source_file.get(email_tail->email_data.to, 50, '|');
        source_file.get(email_tail->email_data.subject, 100, '|');
        source_file.get(email_tail->email_data.contents, 200, '|');

        // If source_file isn't eof, then create a new node, connect the nodes, then have tail point to it, make next NULL
        if(!(source_file.eof())) {
            email_tail->next = new email_node;  // retaining the order emails were sent in, so always adding to the end
            email_tail = email_tail->next;
            email_tail->next = NULL;
        }
    } // end while loop
     return 1;
};
```

Comment: Just one questions: Why `std::ifstream::get` and C-strings instead of `std::getline` and `std::string` objects?

Comment: Our teacher for this class isn't allowing us to use string yet. She insists we use arrays of characters for now. Can I use getline with arrays of characters?

Comment: In that case your approach is just fine :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your loop has empty body because of mistakenly-placed `;`

```
while(!(source_file.eof())); {
                           ^
```

and since there is no code that would set the stream's `eof` flag, it becomes an infinite loop, therefore it seems that the code that follows is never executed.

Comment: I thought that std::ifstream::get removed characters from the stream?

Comment: @DanMinor: Just remove the semicolon.